# How do I avoid pdoc using my src/ directory as a namespace?

Tags: python, pdoc

I have my dev code organized in a `src` directory. I have no **init** file in src, only in the package subdirs under src, like so

```
myprojectdir/
    dist/
    doc/
    src/
        foo/
             __init__.py
             bar.py
    pyproject.toml
    setup.py
    README.md
```

`myprojectdir>pdoc src -o doc` produces output that shows

```
Namespace src
=============

Sub-modules
-----------
* src.foo
```

That is not what I want - I want the `src` gone everywhere from the documentation, that is, I want no namespace and the modules should show up without the `src.` prefix. Alternatively, I want to have the namespace and prefixes renamed. How do I do either?

I understand that Python>3.3 interprets directories without an `__init__` file as namespaces and thus allows `import src`, so I guess that is what pdoc is picking up on.